# Threading problem with Swift search method when using Async Await

Tags: swift, async-await, concurrency, task

I have a search method for a search bar component in my Swift app. Here is the search method:

```swift
@MainActor
func searchLocalPopularTerms(for searchTerm: String, completionHandler: @escaping (() -> Void)) {
    // If timestamp is nil, this is our first search, so set it here
    if self.timestamp == nil {
        self.timestamp = Date()
    }
    
    guard let timestamp else { return }
    
    Task {
        // When we make a request we pass a timestamp into the request
        let searchResults = await self.searchManager.searchResults(searchTerm: searchTerm, gender: self.gender, timestamp: Date())
        
        // We then check if the timestamp returned by the results is great than the stored timestamp.
        // If it is, then these are new results and we can update the searchItems array
        if searchResults.results.isNotEmpty, searchResults.timestamp > timestamp {
            self.searchItems = searchResults.results
            // And then reset the local timestamp to the new current date
            self.timestamp = Date()
        }
        completionHandler()
    }
}
```

Because the SearchManager `searchResults()` method is with `async await` I am trying to make sure that there is no issue with searches i.e. that the searches are done in the correct order and that there are no threading issues. As such I have tried to add a check here whereby I pass a timestamp into the request which then is set against the results when they are returned from the API. When a successful call is made and results returned, I set the local `timestamp` variable. Every time I receive an API response, I am checking the local variable (which will be storing the last successful result timestamp) against the new results. If the new results timestamp is greater than the stored one, I know that this request was indeed made after the most successful one, and so only then do I update the results array.

However, there seems to be something wrong with the implementation as when I type into the search field, sometimes it is clearly not updating with the latest search. It works most of the time, but on occasions if I type very fast, if I have typed, for example, "Sandwiches" if fetches "Sandwi", omitting the last characters. I think there must be something wrong with the way I am implementing this.

Here is an example of where I call this method:

```swift
viewModel?.searchLocalPopularTerms(for: searchText, completionHandler: { [weak self] in
    onMain {
        self?.reloadSection(showKeyboard: true)
        self?.viewModel?.searchTerm = searchText
    }
})
```

And the service method itself:

```swift
private static func searchResults(_ query: String, gender: Gender, popularTerms: [String]? = nil,
                                  allowFredhopperSuggestions: Bool = ConfigManager.shared.allowFredhopperSuggestions, timestamp: Date) async -> SearchResults {
    let suggestionLimits = SearchSuggestionLimits()

    var suggestions: [SearchItem] = []
    suggestions.reserveCapacity(suggestionLimits.totalLimit)

    if allowFredhopperSuggestions {
        let results = await fredhopperSuggestions(query)
        suggestions.append(contentsOf: results)
    } else {
        let designers = designerSearchResults(query, gender: gender, fetchLimit: suggestionLimits.designerLimit)
        suggestions.append(contentsOf: designers)

        let categories = categorySearchResults(query, gender: gender, fetchLimit: suggestionLimits.categoryLimit)
        suggestions.append(contentsOf: categories)
    }

    if let popularTerms = popularTerms {
        let alreadyFoundList = suggestions.compactMap { $0.name }
        let popularSearches = popularTermsSearchResults(query, popularTerms: popularTerms, alreadyFoundList: alreadyFoundList, fetchLimit: suggestionLimits.popularLimit)
        suggestions.append(contentsOf: popularSearches)
    }

    return SearchResults(timestamp: timestamp, results: suggestions)
}
```

Comment: The completion handler basically undoes the safety of async await, you can go from completion handler to async await via a continuation but you should not go from async await to a completion handler without a very very good reason that you can explain and only after you have exhausted everything else. You should watch “Meet async await”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've refactored now so that the search method in the viewModel is as follows:

```
@MainActor
func searchLocalPopularTerms(for searchTerm: String) async {
    let searchResults = await self.searchManager.searchResults(searchTerm: searchTerm, gender: self.gender, timestamp: Date())
    
    if searchResults.results.isNotEmpty {
        self.searchItems = searchResults.results
    }
}
```

And in the viewController we use the task:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        self.searchTask?.cancel()
        let task = Task { [weak self] in
            guard let self else { return }
            await self.viewModel?.searchLocalPopularTerms(for: searchText)
            self.reloadSection(showKeyboard: true)
            self.viewModel?.searchTerm = searchText
        }
        self.searchTask = task
}
```

For each new search, we cancel the previous task

Comment: Nice. FWIW, I would make `searchLocalPopularTerms` a throwing function (in case it was canceled, you really don't want `reloadSection` nor updating the view model).

Answer (score 2):

The timestamp logic has a number of issues:

1. If second search starts before first finishes, they’re both going to capture the same “previous” `timestamp` and both will have a `searchResults.timestamp` that is greater than that. So both will save their search results and you have a race.
2. As an aside, one should never use `Date` as comparison timestamps, as repeated invocations are not guaranteed to be monotonically increasing. There are timestamps that are (e.g., `mach_absolute_time`-based ones, the new `Clock` types, etc.), but all of this timestamp logic should be retired, anyway, so it does not really matter. Just a FYI.
3. Instead, I would simply save the `Task` of the prior search request, and cancel it when submitting the next request. I’d also make sure that your various search functions supported cancelation (i.e., that they don’t introduce further orphaned, unstructured concurrency), that they use cancelable API such as `async`-`await` renditions of `URLSession` API, etc. I would also have the `async` method `searchResults` actually just return the results. There is no need to store the results in a property to be fetched separately. It actually only introduces additional race conditions.

   So, I would simplify it to something like:

   ```swift
   var task: Task<Void, Error>?

   @MainActor
   func searchLocalPopularTerms(for searchTerm: String, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
       // cancel prior task, if any
       task?.cancel()

       // start new search
       task = Task {
           let results = await searchManager.searchResults(searchTerm: searchTerm, gender: gender)

           if !Task.isCancelled {
               self.searchItems = results
           }

           completionHandler()
       }
   }
   ```

   Now, I did not make any assumptions that `searchResults` would throw `CancellationError` if canceled, but if it did (and you made it a method that `throws`), the above is further simplified:

   ```swift
   @MainActor
   func searchLocalPopularTerms(for searchTerm: String, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
       // cancel prior task, if any
       task?.cancel()

       // start new search
       task = Task {
           defer { completionHandler() }
           searchItems = try await searchManager.searchResults(searchTerm: searchTerm, gender: gender)
       }
   }
   ```

   I might also suggest eliminating the completion handler pattern. We use `async`-`await` largely to excise completion handler patterns from our code. E.g.,

   ```swift
   @MainActor
   func searchLocalPopularTerms(for searchTerm: String) async throws {
       task?.cancel()

       task = Task {
           searchItems = try await searchManager.searchResults(searchTerm: searchTerm, gender: gender)
       }

       try await task?.value
   }
   ```

   Now, all of this assumes that `searchResults` is not introducing any unstructured concurrency and that it is using a cancelable API (like `URLSession`), but we cannot comment without seeing its implementation.

   But the take-home message is that one should use cancelation patterns, which renders the timestamps completely unnecessary. It is both more efficient (not even letting canceled requests to continue to execute) and more concise.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and this certainly makes sense. I've edited the question with my changes - thoughts on this? It seems to be working well and in theory, cancelling the previous task with each new request would seem pretty safe...